# Determine why a program is blocked by Windows Defender SmartScreen

Tags: windows, security, windows-10, group-policy, windows-defender

I have installed the Komodo IDE and now I like to activate my license by running file `Komodo-IDE-8-Windows-SC92********.exe` but it is blocked by my Windows Defender:

> **Windows protected your PC**
>
> Windows Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk.
>
> App:       Komodo-IDE-8-Windows-SC92********.exe
> Publisher: Unknown publisher

I have no "Run anyway" button as this is disabled by Group Policies.

I went to our IT security guy and ask him to white-list this program. The problem is, it is running fine on his machine, i.e. it is not blocked by Windows Defender. Basically he doesn't know what to do as it is working for him.

I don't see any (obvious) difference between his machine and my machine, we all received recently new Windows 10 PC's.

I tried to add my file to Antimalware Exclusions in Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Exclusions\Paths` but it did not help.

How Windows Defender knows which programs have to be blocked and how can it be modified?

Note, if one likes to disable or modify the SmartScreen have a look at [Configure Windows Defender SmartScreen](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_8.1_2012R2&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsExplorer::EnableSmartScreen). However, by default the Group Policy is updated every two hours, so the changes might not be persistent. Also, most likely you will breach your company security rules.